# Ubuntu Touch auto login

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've got Ubuntu Touch running on a Nexus 10.

I'd like to bypass the login screen have it autologin and run chrome in full screen mode.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Shouldn't the auto login part be in the Users settings? As for Chrome, that should also be an option, just in Chrome's settings.